# link_to with image, text and css in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a btn (using css) that will have both an image and a text.
I have the following code that works without the class, but when I am adding the class my code breaks. Is there a way to combine all of the above in link_to?

```
<%= link_to new_task_path do %>
   <%= image_tag("new.png"), :class => 'btn btn-info' %> New Task 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with

```
<%= link_to image_tag("new.png") + "New Task" , new_task_path , :class => 'icon btn' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the class on tag(anchor tag)

```
<%= link_to new_task_path, :class => 'btn btn-info' do %>
   <%= image_tag("new.png") %> New Task 
<% end %>
```